# template deduction with SFINAE in c++

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm new to SFINAE. i have noticed that:

```
template <typename T> void f(T t) { t.Crash(); } // version 1
void f(...) { } // The sink.
f(1);

template <typename T> void f(const T& t, typename T::iterator* it = nullptr) { } // version 2
void f(...) { } // The sink.
f(1);
```

in version 2, because of SFINAE, it will not throw any error, and choose the ellipse sink. but why at version 1, the compiler will stop and complain?

Does the SFINAE only apply to the signature not the body? so in version 1, it prefers the template function, but at what stage does the compiler stop and throw an error?

please explain explicitly the **processing stages** of compiler regarding the template overload resolution.

Answer (score 4):

> but why at version 1, the compiler will stop and complain?

```
template <typename T> void f(T t) { t.Crash(); } // version 1
void f(...) { } // The sink.
f(1);
```

There is no substitution failure there in the templated version of `f` above, because `T` can be deduced as `int` from the call `f(1)`. And as per overload resolution rules, the `f<int>(int)` is more prefered than `f(...)`

---

```
template <typename T> void f(const T& t, typename T::iterator* it = nullptr) { } // version 2
void f(...) { } // The sink.
f(1);
```

There is a substitution failure there, because, the compiler will need to deduce the type of `it` after deducing `T` as `int`. It substitutes `int` in place of `int::iterator` which is invalid.

---

SFINAE on functions works in the context of creating valid *function-template specialization*.

> Does the SFINAE only apply to the signature not the body?

You can say something like that... Take a loot at these valid code examples:

```
//Just the declaration
template <typename T>
void f(T t);

void f(...); 

int main(){
    f(1);   //selects f<int>(int)
}
```

Meanwhile:

```
//just the declarations.
template <typename T> 
void f(const T& t, typename T::iterator* it = nullptr);

void f(...);

int main(){
    f(1);   //selects f(...)
}
```